# Bypass UIScrollViewDelegate when scroll in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView which is a child view of a UIScrollView. Is it possible to bypass the UIScrollViewDelegate when there is a scroll inside the UICollectionView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods as like below and bypass your implementations inside that method.

Example:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        guard scrollView != yourCollectionView else{

            return
        }

        //Your implementations goes here
    }
```